# Capture part of a regex match

Tags: java, regex

I want to write a Regex expression that captures the content of `<h1>` tags.

For example I want to capture

```
<h1>All of this in here no matter what 雷 א 格 ןןד i$ </h1>
```

However I do not want the actual `<h1>` tags, just the stuff inside (include foreign characters)

There are lots of very complex answers around, with special conditions, lookarounds, groups. I'm looking for the contents of the tags. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex pattern

```
(?<=<h1>).*?(?=<\\/h1>)
```

Comment: And put the `.*?` in parenthesis and that is the matching group....
Still, using a parser like XML (if it is xhtml) or TagSoup is better.

Comment: @rolfl - No need to use matching group as the entire match is what OP is asking for...

Comment: Sorry to trouble you further, but can you explain how you came up with it? Also, I don't see how it will support foreign characters? Doesn't it need a p{L} somewhere?

Comment: @Imray - Dot `.` represents all characters, not just ASCII, so you should be okay with the pattern as is shown above. Just be sure to use `?u` modifier. Part `.*?` is non-greedy, which means it will take just what it has to. And it is surrounded with lookbehind and lookahead to check a `<h1>` at the beginning  and `</h1>` at the end. Optionally, you can also use `?i` modifier to make to case insensitive, so it will accept for example also `<H1>` tag...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String#replaceAll` like this:

```
String h1text = html.replaceAll("(?ui)<h1>(.*?)</h1>", "$1");
```

Take note of `?u` for dealing with unicode characters and `?i` for ignore case match.

Comment: This is a `round-about way` of capturing text using Java's String API. For capturing one needs more code using Matcher API.

Comment: If we are capturing very long String then it might be but here we're just capturing extra `<h1>` and `</h1>`

Comment: Waste is to replace text by itself.